# Prevent 'snapping' of lines when inline-block divs resize themselves?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm experimenting with making a nicer grid/list container. I'll have a bunch of objects to be displayed in a container, and I want to see them either in list view (where each item takes up 100% of the width and, say, 70px height) or grid view (where each item takes up, say, 100px width and 100px height). I made them all `display: inline-block` too, since they'll automatically position themselves appropriately (assuming the container div is the same width as one list item, which it is).

I want to make a smooth transition between them, so I made a [fiddle to experiment.](http://jsfiddle.net/5387je9h/) This does a good job in animating the size changes for each div, but there's a jarring height transition whenever a row of objects gets either too big or too small for its current row and adds/removes an object. My question is; is there a simple way to animate the objects to their end positions? For example, the sixth object which is at the bottom of the list view would reposition itself to the bottom right of the container in grid view.